# How to clean a class correcly

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a class with functions to read data files. When read the class stores this datas in public properties.

After that I write the content of the puplic properties into a database.

Then it repeates. This means I read again datas with this class.

Before it repeates I want to clean the class.

What is the best way to do it?

Is it better to clear the content of the public properties manually or is it better to dispose the class. Maybe this is the more elegant way to do it?

Comment: How is your class defined?

Comment: `I want to clean the class` <= I have never heard of anyone wanting to "clean" a class. What is your end goal?

Comment: He means reset to it's inital state

Comment: @Igor Probably reset the members to their `default` value

Comment: It seems that you are trying to reuse the variable that reference an instance of a class to represent different objects of the same kind. Don't do it. Just reinitialize the variable and fill it with new values for the properties

Comment: *"clean the class"* - add `Clean()` method and don't forget to call it. Typically you just use `new` (create new instance with default values) instead of *cleaning*. There could be concerns like multi-threading, memory, resources, etc. then cleaning become a better option. Look into `IDisposable` it's a common way to define something what require cleaning, but that approach will bound you to `new`.

Comment: `Look into IDisposable it's a common way to define something what require cleaning` <= Do not do this. @Sinatr - `IDisposable` should be used for release unmanaged resources, it has nothing to do with resetting an instances state.

Comment: I will do it, as described, with help of a clean() function.

Comment: By far the simplest way is to create a new instance of the class.  A bit wasteful but it has a very short lifespan and never makes it out of gen#0.  Gen 0 allocations are never anything to worry about.

Comment: 1. _When read the class stores this datas in public properties_ 2. _..  I read again datas with this class_ - seems like you don't need to do anything. Properties with data will be overwritten with new data.

Comment: @Fabio Not here, because I add keys into dictionarys.

Comment: Show your code, asking questions in "general" will always produce fewer comments with different assumptions. With dictionaries you can use `mydictionary[key] = newValue`. Or use advise from comments above and reassign whole dictionary with new one.

Comment: @Igor, *"it has nothing to do with resetting an instances state"* - I didn't say or mean that. It's clear what disposed object shouldn't be reused. I only want to mention `IDisposable` as addition to `new`, so that OP can check and decide for himself whenever it fits his *cleaning*.

Comment: @Sinatr - again, that is a very poor recommendation including your added comment above. Only implement `IDisposable` on a type that needs to release unmanaged resources/memory, that is the only time it should be implemented. If you want to "clean" an object but do it across multiple types then define your own interface like 'ICleanable' but do not misuse an existing interface with a broad well understood meaning like `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Igor, *"Only implement IDisposable on a type that needs to release unmanaged resources/memory"* - I am also going to be pedantic and just say you are wrong here. `IDisposable` is just an interface, nothing else. Anyone is free to use it whenever it fits (there is no harm). Implementing it will allow caller to decide when to call it (e.g. using nice `using()` construct) and is a sign what you shouldn't forget to call `Dispose()` (static code analyzers will warn you). Again, I have no clue what OP is doing, does he use unmanaged resources, will `IDisposable` fits.. I simply wanted to name it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your class looks similar to:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public double IntField { get; set; }
  public string StringField { get; set; }
}
```

And your application something like:

```
public class MyApp
{
  public void Execute() {
    var myClass = new MyClass();

    // set properties
    myClass.IntField = 123;
    myClass.StringField = "Hello";

    // save to DB
  }
}
```

Each time your application runs, it will run the `Execute` method which will create a new instance of your class. This way all class properties will be empty or "clean" as you call it.

Comment: But this will lead to many instances. Correct?

Comment: yes, it will lead to a new instance of `MyClass` every time the method `execute` is called. Now the real question: is this a problem? Very likely, no. Garbage collector will do a good job on releasing the memory associated to myClass instance; before optimize the code for memory allocation (or for speed, or for every kind of optimization), be sure this is really a problem for your application, and if not aim for code that is better structured and maintainable  instead of "code that save some memory bytes somehow but it's harder to work with"

Comment: Not sure why I was given a down vote but @GianPaolo basically sums up the instance question. These instances will be garbage collected at some point after `Execute` returns.

Comment: As long as your object is less than 86000 bytes, it will be on Gen-0,  Garbage collector will collect is as soon as Execute returns, so there should be no worries.

Answer (score 0):

create new method , name it let say "clear_data" , call it before load data from function that do it . also may be you will need call it from destructor to prevent memory leaks (in case you have pointers that point to some allocated memory ).

Answer (score 0):

What about Memento pattern? Might be useful for you:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186184/Memento-Design-Pattern

Or, as already pointed out, you have 3 other good possibilities:
 - Create a method `Clear()` that sets properties to default value,
 - If you have some unmanaged resources, you can use IDisposable interface,
 - Create static readonly property holding Empty instance of the class and reassign it. But I would go with Memento/Clear way.